# How to remove all kde packages?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, kde

So I recently installed the kde packages, running the command
`apt install kde-full` for installing the kde desktop environment, after test it a while I realize I didn't want it anymore so I remove the packages like this `apt remove kde-full`, but I notice that some packages and applications remains and weren't completely removed.

I am on Debian 8 distribution. I recently turned to the linux world so any help will be appreciated.

[Edit]

I also tried `tasksel --list-task`:

```
u desktop   Debian desktop environment
u gnome-desktop GNOME
u xfce-desktop  Xfce
u kde-desktop   KDE
u cinnamon-desktop  Cinnamon
u mate-desktop  MATE
u lxde-desktop  LXDE
u web-server    web server
u print-server  print server
u ssh-server    SSH server
i laptop    laptop
```

Some packges listing with `synaptic-package-manager`:

[image]

`aptitude why kde-base-artwork` output:

```
aptitude why kde-base-artwork
i   kdeartwork         Depends kscreensaver (>= 4:4.14.2-1)      
i A kscreensaver       Depends kde-workspace-bin                 
i A kde-workspace-bin  Depends kde-workspace-data (= 4:4.11.13-2)
i A kde-workspace-data Depends kde-base-artwork
```

Comment: I was thinking to remove it all by displaying `kde-full` package dependencies and pass it to `apt remove` command , any ideas?

Comment: I have already gnome desktop installed, and I had it when I installed kde

Comment: I installed ubuntu 17.10 so I no longer have a way to verify any answer, so I think this question should be closed

Comment: Have a look at this link. This link will help you.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has said they won't be able to verify any solution

Comment: I think I can't do it myself

Answer (score 3):

After removing `kde-full`,

```
apt autoremove
```

or

```
apt-get autoremove
```

(`apt autoremove` will be available in Debian 9)

should remove any packages that were installed automatically along with `kde-full`. Take care to review the list of packages that are about to be removed before confirming the removal.

Other packages may be marked as *not* automatically installed, *e.g.* `kdeartwork` in your case (for whatever reason). You need to remove those packages and re-run `autoremove`. To identify all the packages you need to remove, look for packages the automatic flag, or run `aptitude why` on packages that *are* automatically installed and look for packages without `A` in the output. After a few iterations you should manage to get rid of all the unwanted packages.

Comment: not showing packges for autoremove

Comment: `kde-full` is ametapackage. It will not remove remaining packages that are part of that. `autoremove` is only for dependencies not needed anymore...

Comment: @nwildner after removing `kde-full`, the “dependencies” that it pulled in should no longer be needed any more (I just checked with another metapackage, in the metapackage section).

Comment: @nwildner more explicitly, for example `kde-full` depends on `kde-plasma-desktop`, so installing `kde-full` installs `kde-plasma-desktop` and marks it as an automatic installation; removing `kde-full` should also remove `kde-plasma-desktop` (depending on the tool being used — apparently `apt` on its own won’t, but `aptitude` will), and if it doesn’t do so directly, `autoremove` *should* catch it (unless some other installed package depends on it or recommends it).